# Google analytics redirect, render 2 page

Tags: google-analytics

When the page loads, after full rendering, google analytics redirects to the same page by adding the get parameter utm_expid. The problem is that the page is essentially rendered 2 times and all files are loaded 2 times, how to solve this problem, tell me who came across?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution: **you have to avoid the redirect**.

Any alternative or missing tracking of a page will alter the data, for example if you don't track the first page you lose the source, if you don't track the second page you lose the interactions made on it.

You can try not to track only the pageview (keeping any events) of the page that has as parameter `utm_expid`, it seems the only compromise, but I do not exclude that they can generate artifacts.